# Increase the number of lines that can be pasted in PuTTY

Tags: putty, copy-paste, r

I use R and recently started working with a Linux server for my job. We are using PuTTY to communicate with the server. With our current workflow, we write scripts in RStudio on our local computers/laptops and then we copy-paste them in the PuTTY console. (`source()` is not really an option when doing interactive data analysis and when a script is not finished yet.)

This works fine most of the time, but if the scripts get longer, I noticed that I get a plus at the end of the line and that not all of my pasted code was executed.

```
+
```

I figured that this is probably because PuTTY might have an upper limit of how much text can be pasted. My solution to this right now is to copy-paste my script bit by bit, which is quite inconvenient because every step might take a few minutes, so I end up babysitting it for more than half an hour.

Is there an option to increase the amount of pastable text in PuTTY that could solve my issue? Sorry if this is kind of a newbie question, I am not very familiar yet with using a console. Thank you for any pointers you might have!

Comment: Try Change Settings > Window > Set Scrollback size.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! In my PuTTY settings, the Scrollback size is indicated as 2000, yet I have never pasted even close to that amount of lines. Could it be that PuTTY calculates lines by number of characters rather than line breaks?

Comment: I don't have PuTTY here. Try a much larger value.

Comment: I tried this out, but unfortunately the issue still persists.